# Reverse request query string back to defined pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I have a route configured like this in my app:

```
config.add_route('book', 'book/{id}).
```

When I make a GET request, e.g `localhost:8000/book/2`, I would like to output route pattern like the one defined in config, so the output would be `'book/{id}'`.

I have tried regex, but maybe there are better ways.

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want literal `{` and `}`or just the digits returned in the output?

Comment: If the former you can use [`proutes`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#displaying-application-routes). The latter would be `request.path_info`.

Comment: I want `/book/{id}` from request path. Basically revert back to the same as in `add_route` pattern.
More specifically: request.url --> some magic --> url pattern. But no idea what that magic is.

Comment: Perhaps [matched_route](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#the-matched-route)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.matched_route.pattern`. I found it by using the `pyramid_debugtoolbar`, searching for "route", and found it under the Request Vars tab with its attributes listed.

Comment: What URL did you visit? `None` implies you did not visit `/book/2`, or as the note in the link in my original comment above states: "If no route URL pattern matches, the `matched_route` object attached to the request will be `None`."

Comment: Yes, you are right. I managed to make a request twice and that wiped pattern out. Thank you!